# passing model into a variable using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, variables, url, model, scope

I would just like to ask if it is possible to pass a model like this {{ ngModel | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }} into a variable for me to be able to pass it to another input type? If it is, how? thank you

Answer (score 0):

the value present in ng-model is accessible throughout the page (and in controller using $scope). So you just need to set ng-model = "your variable" as an attribute to any other input type and you can access same variable in multiple input elements within a page.  If this doesn't solve your problem, can you please elaborate a little more what exactly you want to achieve? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:-

```
 <div ng-app="" ng-init="model.date='1288323623006'">
  <p>Enter Your Date Here: <input type="text" ng-model="model.date"></p>
  <span>{{model.date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
 </div>
```

Here model.date is having time in timestamp.